# Aws IoT Core Custom Authorizer(https)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

I want to publish to a topic in Iot Core using Custom Authorizer with **signing disabled** and POST method. In documentation there is no information how to pass username and password.

I tried following command,

```
curl -v -X POST 'https://[iot-core-endpoint]:443/topics/test/topic?qos=0' \
 -H "x-amz-customauthorizer-name: test-authorizer" \
 -H "Host: [iot-core-endpoint]" \
 -H "Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}'
```

got `{"message":"Forbidden","traceId":"27ffe348-407c-249d-3b78-5cfdc6239573"}` and there is no log in Iot Core and Lambda function.

According to docs it is not clear how to add username/password to request or if it is supported.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth.html

Is https publish supported without signing disabled, if so how can I add username/password to request?